# Layout of iOS app gets disoriented when built on different iphone simulators

Tags: ios, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwtbM.png)

I have set the constraints from the safe area for every labels and textfields but the problem is still occurring. The app perfectly sets only on iphone 11 and iphone 12 simulators only.
(Have shared the screenshot)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. We need a lot more information about how you've setup your constraints to try and offer any help.

Answer (score 0):

> I have set the constraints from the safe area for every labels and textfields

No, you don't. If you did, you would not have this problem. You have not correctly set the *trailing* constraints for these views. In fact, it looks like *none* of your views has correct constraints.

Every view must be completely configured through constraints as to its *position* and its *size*. It must, in other words, be bounded top, left, bottom, and right. Labels and text fields and buttons have an automatic height so you don't need to fix their bottoms, but all of *your* views need top, left, and right constraints.